# Android: Diffenece Between SMS Sent & Delivered Status

Tags: android, sms

I'm not clear on the difference between SMS **Sent** & **Delivered** status. Can anyone make it clear to me plz?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sent: it got to the server from your phone.

Delivered: it got to the recipient from the server.

Comment: I got no SIM Card in the phone and i was getting SMS_SENT intent. Technically it should'nt .

Answer (score 7):

**Sent**: The mobile device has sent the SMS to the SMSC (Short message service center). And the SMSC has confirmed it has received the SMS.

**Delivered**: The mobile device has received a SMS-DELIVER (Delivery Notification). Although delivered is a relative term in the SMS world. Sometimes SMSC's will say it's delivered when in fact it has only be relayed to another SMSC and has not infact been yet delivered to the destination mobile device.